# Command like inotify - or another solution?

Tags: files, command-line

Is it possible to recursively scan changed files from more than 3 weeks ago with `inotify`, or is `inotify` only for starting `cron` jobs? What other command can I try for checking for changed files that are more than 3 weeks old?

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be looking for `find`. Inotify is more of an event mechanism for live updates, whereas `find` enables you to search for files based on criteria such as -cmin, -ctime, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As "Jo-Erlend Schinstad" said... you can use `find`

Example:

```
find . -mtime +5 | xargs ls -l
```

`.` -> current directory (recursive search is by default)

`-mtime +5` -> find all files which are older than 5 days (this is for creation time, not last change time!)

`| xargs ls -l` -> only for listing file detail (you can remove this)

Comment: when I want to check of last 31 days ( what has been modified as file ) all directories on harddisk then I type this ? : find * -type f -mtime +31 -printf '%s Byte(s)\n' >> find-modified-001.txt

Comment: if you want to check all files just go to / or replace . with /

Comment: if you want to find all files older (creation time) than 31 days you must run this: "find / -type f -mtime +31"